# Sort Semester by using drop box

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort courses  based on semester (Fall, Spring, and Both)
     PHP:

```
  <td width="200" bgcolor="#DCDCDC" <strong>Semester Available</strong>
  <select name="selectSemester" id="selectSemester">
      <option>Sort Semester</option>
      <option value="0">Fall</option>
      <option value="1">Spring</option>
      <option value="2">Both</option>
    </select>
  </td>


  SQL:

   if($_POST['selectSemester'] != 0)
   {
   $selectSemester=$_POST['selectSemester'];
    }
```

Comment: I want to have drop down which will sort a table based on the selection. For example, if the user chooses Fall, I would like my query to only show courses with a semester_available of 0. (0 is how Fall courses are stored in the database, 1 is Spring, and 2 is Both). It is not currently sorting them at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you exactly want to do.
If you get the courses by an SQL query, you can use

`ORDER BY semester`

or if you actually want to filter by semester you can use

`WHERE semester = $_POST['selectSemester']`